# Redis poping multiple elements from a list

Tags: redis, redis-cluster

I am looking on LPOP and LPOPRPUSH as a valid options for an atomic action to pop value.
However I have a job that every 2 seconds pops 1000 values from that list - which is 1000 requests to Redis.
I would have used SPOP which can return X values back in one request. But those are randon ones and not the most left ones.
I do need to pop them from the left side of the list.

What are my options to do it the fastest, without locking and atomic? I have multiple servers that access this list and I can't retrieve duplicate values (That's why LRANGE doesn't work for me)

**EDIT**
The more I'm thinking about it the more I see that I need to compromise and use SPOP.

The scenario is batching inserts into the DB with Redis. Instead of thousands inserts a sec to MySQL - I'm pushing to Redis and every 2sec get the values and insert in one go to MySQL.

I guess I can use SPOP if I will add timestamp to the actual value in Redis, and to avoid the possibility where a value can be stuck in the set forever I will run a loop of `SPOP x 1000` until null.

Comment: Have you looked into using transactions? The full transaction is atomic and one request, but is multiple commands executed sequentially (which may be what you are trying to avoid, instead looking for a single command)

Comment: Did you try `lrange` with `ltrim` in the `multi`/`exec` or inside the lua ?

Comment: I read about this option, but haven't tried as I would like a simple solution without possible failures (no rollback in redis transactions).

Comment: `lrange` will act as `read` and `ltrim` will act as `write/update` and it will be in that order, so even you fail at read, it won't affect the write so the list will not be in a dirty state.

Comment: In theory, can two sessions read the same objects?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There're to options:

1. Use Lua script to pop N elements in a single `EVAL` command:

```
EVAL 'local result = {}; for i = 1, ARGV[1] do result[i] = redis.call("lpop", KEYS[1]) end; return result' 1 key N
```

2. Use [Redis pipeline](https://redis.io/topics/pipelining) to send N `LPOP` commands to reduce RTT.

Comment: What if something fails in the middle and the values already poped?

Comment: Normally it won't fail, unless Redis gets OOM problem, connection to Redis is broken, or Redis is down you might lose some data.

Comment: Also `SPOP` has similar problems. Normally you don't need to worry about that.

Comment: Can you name the advantages (if any) of those 3 options over each other?

Comment: Lua script guarantees atomicity (client gets 1, 2, 3, ..., N elements), while pipeline does not (client might get 1, 3, 6, 8... elements). Both methods guarantee that elements are popped from from the left of the list, while SPOP does not guarantee that